# Change cell value of column A of column B is equal to specific text

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, if-statement

[image]

I'm trying to create a macro in excel to help separate two stores with the same name of "Store 1". I want to be able to change the store name (Column B) of a product if the product code (column A) match the following. " 10004,10005,10006". How can I go about it creating a VBA macro to do this?

Resulting something like so:

[image]

Comment: Will it match with `1004,1005` or `10004,10005 etc...` Do you want formula solution or vba solution?

Comment: sorry correct it, should match the "10004,10005 etc.". and VBA please as i don't think a formula would help much in this situation

Comment: Check my answer and feedback please.

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub.

```
Sub ChangeStore()
Dim lr As Long
Dim rng As Range

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each rng In Range("A2:A" & lr)
        If (rng = 10004) Or (rng = 10005) Or (rng = 10006) Then
            rng.Offset(, 1) = "Store 2"
        End If
    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: If your criteria is sequential then could use `If (rng >= 10004) And (rng <= 10006) Then`.

Comment: Thank you this seemed to work, the Product codes i used were placeholders for the actual codes are like Barcode numbers, "43234" for example. Is there limit to how many `or` you can add? I currently have a list of about 20 product codes that would be changed to "Store 2". is it possible to put all the rng codes in an array?

Comment: May limit is 256. If many reference then could use array.